# How do scrape big images from navigation?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying scrape big versions of images in navigation from "https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/16722/Ferrari/488-GTB-488-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=785&yearId=5447". Unfortunately, my code only gets those tiny images.

```
collected_HTML_Tag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//nav/ul/li[1]/a/img").get_attribute('src')
print(collected_HTML_Tag)
```

How can I improve my code to get above mentioned images ?

For better understanding example consider following images. I need images marked in red.

[image: image1] and [image: image2]

Comment: Do you want to download this big Images

Comment: Yes. The ones marked, 4 of them in total

Answer (score 0):

You can download all 4 images using below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Function of downloading Image in current folder
def downloadImage(driver, j):
    with open(f'Image{j}.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        l = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/ak-app/div[1]/abstract/products/section/product-details/section[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/img')
        file.write(l.screenshot_as_png)


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/16722/Ferrari/488-GTB-488-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=785&yearId=5447')

# Click Next Image
for j in range(1, 5):
    print(j)
    if j != 1:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            f'/html/body/ak-app/div[1]/abstract/products/section/product-details/section[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[{j}]/a/img').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    downloadImage(driver, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Selenium, you can get these image_urls in less than a second just using requests, there is a backend api request that you can recreate from the given url:

```
import requests

given_url = 'https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/16722/Ferrari/488-GTB-488-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=785&yearId=5447'
code = given_url.split('/')[6] #get car code
suffix = given_url.split('?')[-1] #get endpart of url

headers =   {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url = f'https://www.akrapovic.com/api2/en-US/products/car/{code}?$inlinecount=allpages&{suffix}'
resp = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

images = [x['Image'] for x in resp['ProductImages']]
print(images)
```

That api url can be found in your browser's Developer Tools - Network tab - fetch/Xhr (then refresh the page and you'll see it load)